# Efficient way to select strings from a list based on a certain condition

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings, I want to filter out these strings base on a given year. for example, in the below list, I only want strings with years above 2018 and also strings that don't contain years. My solution is current, I just need a better way to do this.

```
data = [
    '/soccer/zimbabwe/premier-soccer-league/results/',
    '/soccer/zimbabwe/premier-soccer-league-2020/results/',
    '/soccer/zimbabwe/premier-soccer-league-2019/results/',
    '/soccer/zimbabwe/premier-soccer-league-2018/results/',
    '/soccer/zimbabwe/premier-soccer-league-2017/results/']
```

my script

```
import re

for i in data:
    match = re.match(r".*([1-3][0-9]{3})",i)
    if match is not None: 
        if match.group(1) > '2018':
            print(i)
    else:
        print(i)
```

expected output:

```
data = [
    '/soccer/zimbabwe/premier-soccer-league/results/',
    '/soccer/zimbabwe/premier-soccer-league-2017/results/',
    '/soccer/zimbabwe/premier-soccer-league-2019/results/']
```

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. Also, why is that your expected output? 2017 is not above 2018, but 2020 is. Based on your description, your code is already correct. BTW, if you want more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Try `[x for x in data if re.search(r'\b(201[89]|20[2-9]\d|[3-9]\d{3}|\d{5,})\b') or re.search(r'^(?!.*\b\d{4}\b)', x)]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for your solution, exactly what I needed, but you forgot to add the second argument in the first `re.search`

Comment: Yes, I wrote it without testing. You can even shorten it. Wait, did you mean "2018 included"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append the values to a list (`result` in the below code). You can do like this,

```
import re

result = []
for i in data:
    match = re.match(r'.*(\d{4})', i)
    if match:
        if int(match.group(1)) > 2018:
            result.append(i)
    else:
        result.append(i)
```

Output:

```
['/soccer/zimbabwe/premier-soccer-league/results/',
 '/soccer/zimbabwe/premier-soccer-league-2020/results/',
 '/soccer/zimbabwe/premier-soccer-league-2019/results/']
```

**EDIT:**

The approach without using the loop.

```
def is_match(s, year):
    match = re.match(r'.*(\d{4})', s)
    return match is None or int(match.group(1)) > year

result = list(filter(lambda seq: is_match(seq, 2018), data))
```

Comment: I need a better way to achieve the answer without using a loop

Comment: @benjaminolise Updated the answer without using a loop.

Comment: @benjamin is there a way I can pass the year as a parameter, I don't want to explicitly write the year within the function.

Comment: @benjaminolise Updated the code accordingly.

Comment: @benjaminolise Please let me know does this resolve your issue.